# How to graph by 7 day periods in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power Bi gives you the option to look at data by Year, Quarter, Month, and Day.  I want the ability to look at data by 7 day periods that start on a specific date (not necessarily Monday or Sunday).  How is the best way to accomplish this? I am guessing it will be with a measure but I can't quite figure out what the measure should look like?

Here I know I can assign a day of the week to each row and then use Week Day on my date axis. My problem is I need to be able to put "Tuesday" in the second parameter instead of either 1. Sunday or 2. Monday.

```
Week Number = WEEKNUM(Sheet1[Date],2)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following might work:

```
Week number = WEEKNUM(DATEADD([Date],1,DAY),2)
```